# javascript jQuery code file not working when linked from HTML

Tags: javascript

hi I am new to Javascript and I am trying to use jQuery but it doesn't work if I'm using it on another js file, but if directly inputted into my HTML file it works.

Here is the try.js file:

```
$("#btn1").click(fn1);

function fn1(){
    $("#heading1").fadeToggle();
}
```

and the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript trial ANIMATIONS </title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="try.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 id="heading1">SETTING UP JQUERY</h2>
        <button id="btn1">click me</button>

    </body>


<HTML>
```

Also how can I see the library of jQuery while typing in another js file. I'm using vs code

Comment: Have you download jquery in your folder thats why you are using it like this ? `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Link your JS file just before the closing body tag. That might be the problem, coz while binding click event, the element with id "btn1" would not have been rendered, and that is why, event would not have been bind.

Comment: yes @AlwaysHelping

Comment: tried it but still the same problem @PranavRustagi

Comment: Did you try moving `script` tag for `try.js` after `button` element?

Comment: I would try putting it in a document.ready check.  Your dom elements may not be rendered yet.  Or perhaps you just need to move the include to the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use manipulation with dom when document will been load.

```
function fn1(){
    $("#heading1").fadeToggle();
} 

$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(fn1);
});
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to paste your code into my try.js file but it still not working. I tried to put the one on my try.js file inside my HTML file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) question. You might get an idea on how to proceed.